# Simple interactivity on a SSR Next.js Page

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have this code that just feels wrong

```
"use client";
//Client side rendering for a nav seems useless just to have a show hide button
import { useState } from "react";

export default function NavBar() {
  const [isNavOpen, setIsNavOpen] = useState(true);

  return (
[...]
<div
          className={`${isNavOpen ? "hidden" : ""} w-full md:block md:w-auto`}
          id="navbar-default"
        >
```

I want the nav to be server side rendered, for speed, but on mobile I have a button I want to click to show hide. How can I hydrate this page with the script instead of rendering the entire component client side? There has to be a way to do simple show/hides with a server side component no?

Answer (score -2):

You can create the Navbar as another component and then pass the `isNavOpen` using props. But it's recommended that, if a component has interactivity, it should be a client side component.

https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started/react-essentials#when-to-use-server-and-client-components

Comment: What about an accordion with seo important content?